# stockquote api, fail to printing text color

Tags: html, css, ajax, api, laravel-5

I have created Real Time API for BSE and BSE stock exchange which is working fine and giving live rate of stock. Right I am using SENSEX api and trying to change text color as per my below requirements:

If current time rate is more than previous sec rate, then GREEN color and vise-versa then RED color..

If current rate is equal to previous rate. then no change in color. as it is color.

Here is result of my API in console:

```
{lastprice: "37,290.67", changed: "-294.84", open: 37, low: "37,242.85", high: "37,745.44",…}
```

This is my **AJAX** code:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    url: "{{url('live/change_stoke_market_value_live')}}",
    data: {
      "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
      if (!res) {
        alert('Something went wrong')
      } else {

        console.log(res)

        $('#sensex').html(

          ' <div class="float-right">\n' +
          '        <i class="mdi mdi-account-multiple widget-icon"></i>\n' +
          '        </div>\n' +
          '        <h5 class="text-muted font-weight-normal mt-0" title="Number of Customers">SENSEX</h5>\n' +
          '        <h4 class="mt-3 mb-3">' + res.lastprice + ' (' + res.changed + ')</h4>\n'


        )
        if (res.lastprice.indexOf("+") != -1) {

          document.getElementById("sensex").className = "greenText";
        } else {


          document.getElementById("sensex").className = "redText";
        }

      }
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
.greenText {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgb(83, 241, 83);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.redText {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: Red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a id="sensex"></a>
</li>
```

I dont know what is the wrong...**API and RATE is working fine but.. there no color change**.

Comment: Do you have this live somewhere?

Comment: Ok, if you want me to help you debug, I need to see it.

Comment: I'm here, but there's no easy way to trigger chat that I'm aware of.

Comment: Are you there ? @SergChernata

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180373/discussion-between-serg-chernata-and-kinnari).

Comment: I am really sorry, i am late @SergChernata I am in chat now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a very simple issue of `css` specificity. We troubleshooted by adding `!important` to text color declarations in classes.

```css
.greenText {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgb(83, 241, 83) !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.redText {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: Red !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```